# Why can I modify an immutable object by re-affect it into a variable reference?

Tags: swift, immutability

I have an immutable friend object, I pass it in a class function and put it into a VAR variable.
Even if the reference is immutable, I can modify it and the compiler doesn't complain.

In the following code, if I don't change:

```
let mutableFriend = entity
```

by

```
var mutableFriend = entity
```

I get a:

> Cannot pass an immutable as inout argument: 'friend' is a 'let' constant

**Why is it possible to do that?**

```
class FriendParser {
  class func parse(json: JSON, into entity: Friend)
  {
    var mutableFriend = entity
    guard let _ = try? setupFriend(friend: &mutableFriend, json: json) else {
       log.error("big fail during parsing")
    }
  }
}

let friend = Friend()
let jsonData = Request.requestFriend()
FriendParser.parse(json: jsonData, into: friend)
```

with

```
fileprivate class func setupFriend(friend:inout Friend, json:JSON) throws {}
```

Comment: Class instances aren't mutable/mutable. A `let` reference is a constant. Ie you can't assign a different reference to that constant.

Comment: I guess a nice fix here is to simply change the setupFriend function to: fileprivate class func setupFriend(friend: Friend, json:JSON) throws {}
then if I change friend's properties inside setupFriend() it should update the object in the memory. inout is useless here. right?

Answer (score 1):

If you reference any object with a let, you can alter object's properties, call methods, but you can't assign a different object to that identifier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Friend-object to be truly immutable, you can create an optional initializer, and set all properties of the Friend-class to let-constants.

Something like this:

```
class Friend {
    let name : String

    init?() {
        let someCondition = true
        guard someCondition else { return nil }
        name = "Name"
    }
}

if let friend = Friend() {
    //The row below gives this error: Cannot assign to property, 'name' is a 'let' constant
    //    friend.name = ""
}
```

It's the let-declaration of a property/object that declares it as a constant. It's underlying properties are still mutable (if specified as such, i.e. var's).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block changing name of a `Friend` just make it

```
private(set) var name: String
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an error that may occur with inout arguments. We cannot use an immutable let value as an argument when an inout argument is needed.

- > This makes sense. A constant cannot be modified.

Comment: The problem here is that the original object reference -let friend- is immutable. So I shouldn't be able to pass it inout to setupFriend() but with this var mut = friend trick, the same reference (but now mutable) can be passed to the function. very very disturbing.

Comment: @Mikael But `mutableFriend` is a mutable *copy* of the reference. `entity` will still refer to the same instance (as it's a constant). It's unclear exactly what you find so disturbing.

Comment: you're right. @Hamish. Just a programming mistake here. my bad. I m gonna remove the question as it doesn't really make sense.